# Потеря данных Android приложением после перезапуска

Tags: android, android-service

Пишу Android приложение, в котором есть BackgroundService. Сервис получает данные из некоего api и этот процесс может длиться несколько часов. Каждый раз, когда запрос к api вернул какие-либо данные, сервис выполняет SendBroadcast, отправляя полученные данные в кастомный Receiver, который в свою очередь обращается к активити, чтобы она отобразила эти данные. Когда сервис заканчивает свою работу, вызывается StopForeground, отправляется звуковое оповещение пользователю и появляется уведомление в "шторке". Когда пользователь кликает на уведомление, то открывается активити, в которой отображаются данные, полученные из api.

Всё прекрасно работает за исключением одной детали. Дело в том, что пользователь не будет сидеть в приложении на протяжении всего времени работы сервиса, скорее всего он свернёт приложение или даже отложит телефон в сторону. Соответственно Android в какой-то момент остановит приложение, и когда пользователь нажмёт на уведомление в "шторке", то приложение запустится заново, уже без данных, полученных из api. А сервис к тому времени тоже будет остановлен, следовательно данные окажутся потеряны. Можно ли как-то сохранить эти данные до повторного запуска приложения?

Единственный вариант который я вижу - это сохранять их в файл и читать при запуске активити, но это всё же потребует дополнительных разрешений для приложения да и выглядит несколько коряво.

Comment: Дополнительное разрешение требуется только для записи/чтения общедоступного хранилища, для приватных файлов приложения ничего не требуется [WriteInternalStorage](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files#WriteInternalStorage). В остальном ничего корявого - если данные не должны потеряться, их нужно сохранять.

Comment: @woesss спасибо большое!